# PHP/mySQL: INSERT INTO is not posting the correct values

Tags: php, html, mysql

I try to insert some values from a form into my database with this code:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("myHost", "myUsername", "myPW", "myDB");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$name1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['plannercolumn1']);
$name2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['plannercolumn2']);
$name3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['plannercolumn3']);
$name4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['plannercolumn4']);
$name5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['plannercolumn5']);
$name6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['plannercolumn6']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen (FR_PM) VALUES ('$name1')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen (SA_AM) VALUES ('$name2')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen (SA_PM) VALUES ('$name3')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen (SO_AM) VALUES ('$name4')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen (SO_PM) VALUES ('$name5')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen (MO_AM) VALUES ('$name6')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Name ", $name1, " erfolgreich eingetragen. Wir freuen uns auf dich!";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

When I submit the form, it's creating a new row, but it's not inserting any values in all of the columns, but the column MO_AM. Is there a fault in my PHP?

Comment: My god why so many inserts for 1 query?

Comment: oh wow. yes i changed that now to `$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen (FR_PM, SA_AM, SA_PM, SO_AM, SO_PM, MO_AM) VALUES ('$name1, $name2, $name3, $name4, $name5, $name6')";`

Comment: if you waht to insert one row try this:`$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen (FR_PM,SA_AM,SA_PM,SO_AM,SO_PM,SO_PM) VALUES ('$name1','$name2','$name3','$name4','$name5','$name6')";`

Comment: to answer your question yes, there's a fault, but it's not in your php, it's your use of MySQL.

Comment: Yup, I figured that out. Very stupid fault by me. Too tired to work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should look like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen 
(FR_PM,SA_AM,SA_PM,SO_AM,SO_PM,MO_AM) 
VALUES ('$name1','$name2','$name3','$name3','$name4','$name5','$name6')";
```

Are you sure that the $name variables have values?

Comment: No, sometimes some of the $name variables are empty and some are filled. So how could I manage this, when a $name variable is empty, that it just inserts a blank value?

Comment: Then set variable value to empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL Query should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `anmeldungen`(`FR_PM`,`SA_AM`,`SA_PM`,`SO_AM`,`SO_PM`,`MO_AM`) 
                VALUES ('$name1','$name2','$name3','$name4','$name5','$name6')";
```

Though you shouldn't be using $variable as the insert you should look to binding these to prevent SQL Injections.

Comment: Ye, figured that out already. The thing is that some of the values are empty sometimes. So the column count does not match the value count :/

Comment: In that instance, within your database you need to allow some of these fields to allow NULL. or simply add conditions to your php to state to the user that they must fill in all fields etc..

Comment: So I gonna allow NULL. The user doesn't have to fill in all fields.

Comment: Yes, simply allow NULL on the columns within your database side.

Comment: `ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO anmeldungen (FR_PM, SA_AM, SA_PM, SO_AM, SO_PM, MO_AM) VALUES (', test, test, test, , '). Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`  So $name1, $name5 and $name6 are blank in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What you did just overwrite the query.You can insert multiple values into the same table. 
Change your query:-

EDIT:
If you use multiple lines for the query it should look like this.
Also When you append the variable.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO anmeldungen (FR_PM,SA_AM,SA_PM,...)'
      .' VALUES ('.$name1.','.$name2.','. .... .)'
      ;
```

Comment: Ye, figured that out already. The thing is that some of the values are empty sometimes. So the column count does not match the value count :/

Comment: Can your column accept null record? Or it is compulsory to have a value for the record?